# use react-transition-group as child component receives new props

Tags: css, reactjs, animation, react-transition-group

I have a child component where I would like to use `slide-out` animation as new props are getting passed to it and I try to use react-transition-group/switch-transition but is not really clear how to use it

The child component render method looks as it follows

```js
return (
  <SwitchTransition mode="out-in">
    <CSSTransition
      classNames="slide"
    >
      <div className={classnames("fields-group", containerClass)}>
        {/* <pre>{JSON.stringify(this.props.fields, null, 2)}</pre>*/}

        {fields}
      </div>
    </CSSTransition>
  </SwitchTransition>
);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are more things you need to do:

1. `CSSTransition` should has a prop `key`. When it changed, the transition will take affect.
2. You need to add the transition styles by yourself because, `React Transition Group is not an animation library like React-Motion, it does not animate styles by itself.` <sub>[reference](https://reactcommunity.org/react-transition-group/#:~:text=it%20does%20not%20animate%20styles%20by%20itself.)</sub>

So the child component will look something like that:

```jsx
function Child({ propToAnimate }) {
  return (
    <>
      <h4>Child Component</h4>
      <div className="main">
        <SwitchTransition mode="out-in">
          <CSSTransition
            key={propToAnimate}
            addEndListener={(node, done) => {
              node.addEventListener("transitionend", done, false);
            }}
            classNames="fade"
          >
            <div className="button-container">
              <div className="animate">
                <pre>state: {propToAnimate}</pre>
              </div>
            </div>
          </CSSTransition>
        </SwitchTransition>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

And the styles (for slide animation for example):

```css
.fade-enter .animate {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}
.fade-enter-active .animate {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateX(0%);
}
.fade-exit .animate {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateX(0%);
}
.fade-exit-active .animate {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateX(100%);
}
.fade-enter-active .animate,
.fade-exit-active .animate {
  transition: opacity 500ms, transform 500ms;
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/switchtransition-child-component-dk4jo

Comment: Thanks a lot for the nice explanation!